# Faster way to threshold a 4-D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 4D numpy array of size (98,359,256,269) that I want to threshold.
Right now, I have two separate lists that keep the coordinates of the first 2 dimension and the last 2 dimensions. (mag_ang for the first 2 dimensions and indices for the last 2).

size of  indices : (61821,2)

size of  mag_ang : (35182,2)

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
inner_points = []

for k in indices:
    x = k[0]
    y = k[1]
    for i,ctr in enumerate(mag_ang):
        mag = ctr[0]
        ang = ctr[1]
        if X[mag][ang][x][y] > 10:
            inner_points.append((y,x))
```

This code works but it's pretty slow and I wonder if there's any more pythonic/faster way to do this?s

Comment: What do you mean by "that I want to threshold" ? Do you want to know the precise list of (x, y) corresponding to the X that were above the threshold ? Or is your real goal to get the bounding box for x and y ?

Comment: I want to get another list of x,y that corresponds to the X that's above the threshold

Comment: So, the posted code would have duplicates. Are you interested only in the unique ones?

Comment: Yes, I thought I could probably just do an np.unique on the resulting array(one extra line of code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(EDIT: added a second alternate method)

Use numpy multi-array indexing:

```
import time

import numpy as np

n_mag, n_ang, n_x, n_y = 10, 12, 5, 6
shape = n_mag, n_ang, n_x, n_y
X = np.random.random_sample(shape) * 20

nb_indices = 100 # 61821
indices = np.c_[np.random.randint(0, n_x, nb_indices), np.random.randint(0, n_y, nb_indices)]

nb_mag_ang = 50 # 35182
mag_ang = np.c_[np.random.randint(0, n_mag, nb_mag_ang), np.random.randint(0, n_ang, nb_mag_ang)]

# original method
inner_points = []
start = time.time()
for x, y in indices:
    for mag, ang in mag_ang:
        if X[mag][ang][x][y] > 10:
            inner_points.append((y, x))
end = time.time()
print(end - start)

# faster method 1:
inner_points_faster1 = []
start = time.time()
for x, y in indices:
    if np.any(X[mag_ang[:, 0], mag_ang[:, 1], x, y] > 10):
        inner_points_faster1.append((y, x))
end = time.time()
print(end - start)

# faster method 2:
start = time.time()
# note: depending on the real size of mag_ang and indices, you may wish to do this the other way round ?
found = X[:, :, indices[:, 0], indices[:, 1]][mag_ang[:, 0], mag_ang[:, 1], :] > 10
# 'found' shape is (nb_mag_ang x nb_indices)
assert found.shape == (nb_mag_ang, nb_indices)
matching_indices_mask = found.any(axis=0)
inner_points_faster2 = indices[matching_indices_mask, :]
end = time.time()
print(end - start)

# finally assert equality of findings
inner_points = np.unique(np.array(inner_points))
inner_points_faster1 = np.unique(np.array(inner_points_faster1))
inner_points_faster2 = np.unique(inner_points_faster2)
assert np.array_equal(inner_points, inner_points_faster1)
assert np.array_equal(inner_points, inner_points_faster2)
```

yields

```
0.04685807228088379
0.0
0.0
```

(of course if you increase the shape the time will not be zero for the second and third)

Final note: here I use "unique" at the end, but it would maybe be wise to do it upfront for the `indices` and `mag_ang` arrays (except if you are sure that they are unique already)

Comment: great! :) I added an alternate method without for loop but not sure it is actually faster, depending on the indexation sizes - you'll see with your context

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy` directly. If `indices` and `mag_ang` are numpy arrays of two **columns** each for the appropriate coordinate:

```
(x, y), (mag, ang) = indices.T, mag_ang.T
index_matrix = np.meshgrid(mag, ang, x, y).T.reshape(-1,4)
inner_mag, inner_ang, inner_x, inner_y = np.where(X[index_matrix] > 10)
```

Now you the `inner...` variables hold arrays for each coordinate. To get a single list of pars you can zip the `inner_y` and `inner_x`.

Comment: I'm getting an error    (x,y) = indices

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

My indices is a 2-d array of shape (61821,2)

Comment: I'll try using x = indices[:,0] and y = indices[:,1]?

Comment: inner_mag, inner_ang, inner_x, inner_y = np.where(X[mag, ang, x, y] > 10)

IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (35182,) (35182,) (61821,) (61821,)

Comment: I thought maybe using X[: , :, x,y] > 10 might be good enough(the index mag_ang is just a list of all possible combinations of mag and ang)  but i got inner_mag, inner_ang, inner_x, inner_y = np.where(X[:, :, x, y] > 10)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)

Comment: I got an error when I tried making it into a meshgrid. It seems that my array is too big for this to work..(your answer is most probably the right/most pythonic one if only my array was smaller)  ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.

Answer (score 1):

Here are few vecorized ways leveraging [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
thresh = 10
mask = X[mag_ang[:,0],mag_ang[:,1],indices[:,0,None],indices[:,1,None]]>thresh
r = np.where(mask)[0]
inner_points_out = indices[r][:,::-1]
```

For larger arrays, we can compare first and then index to get the mask -

```
mask = (X>thresh)[mag_ang[:,0],mag_ang[:,1],indices[:,0,None],indices[:,1,None]]
```

If you are only interested in the unique coordinates off `indices`, use the mask directly -

```
inner_points_out = indices[mask.any(1)][:,::-1]
```

For large arrays, we can also leverage multi-cores with `numexpr` module.

Thus, first off import the module -

```
import numexpr as ne
```

Then, replace `(X>thresh)` with `ne.evaluate('X>thresh')` in the computation(s) listed earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.where`

```
inner = np.where(X > 10)
a, b, x, y = zip(*inner)
inner_points = np.vstack([y, x]).T
```